# Autocomplete with MySQL Fulltext search that proposes words instead of results

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

There are lots of question around fulltext searches with mySQL and I've read lots of them without finding what I am looking for (in google or stackoverflow).

I am not looking to match rows (or documents) but I am looking to match words contained in the rows.

For ex, imagine you have a companies table, with an id, a name and a small_description column. You could find rows like :

```
1 | MyBaker | fine bakery since 1920
2 | Bakery factory | all the materials for a bakery
etc...
```

now, when the user types "bak", I would like to suggest him the word "bakery" (and I do not want to directly suggest him MyBaker and Bakery factory since there are hundreds of companies that will match but only a handful different words)

**I think that the underlying mySQL fulltext engine is already having some kind of "word lookup", so I'd like to use that** instead of parsing the name and small_description myself to recreate another table with word | nb_occurences

(not to mention that it may be hard to keep synchronized if lots of update are done in the other table to decrement the counters :( )

**the reason behind this is to create an autocomplete search 
where word suggestions will be correlated to the database content**

For ex, amazon (.fr) is doing a pretty awful job. If you type "tel", it will suggest a dozen "telephone" matches and 0 "television" or "telescope" or "telemetry" ... !

while this is not really a problem in desktop where typing the full word is fast, for mobile it is really a problem

this is amplified by the fact that some words suggested by the smartphone keyboard are not in my database AND that some words of my database are never suggested by the smartphone keyboard.

for ex, my database have 0 telephone and television but lots of telemetry and teleconference

finally, I'd also like to forgive bad spelling if possible (ex : telme should match telemetry)

I hope someone can help me to leverage the existing fulltext index to achieve my goal

Answer (score 1):

FULLTEXT search finds rows of data matching the word or words you present to it. As you know, it is not simply a word search.

You could, in your back-end program, take the results of your FULLTEXT search, break it up into words, and consider the most frequent of those words for autocompletion. This might work well if you modified your searches using [`WITH QUERY EXPANSION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html).

(Keep in mind that natural language FULLTEXT searches work strangely with small sets of data to search, so test with a table with many rows, not just a few.)

But, FULLTEXT does not handle stemming  (chateau + chateaux - chat) correctly, nor does it offer to correct misspellings.

You could use Apache Lucene for your purpose, but it is a large and complex system.

I think you need the word / nb_appearances table, unpleasant as it is to maintain.  It will give you the capability of doing

```
    SELECT word 
      FROM words
      WHERE word LIKE CONCAT(:input,'%')
     ORDER BY nb_appearances DESC;
```

to get partial word matches. FULLTEXT cannot do that. You can also add a second lookup table to correct common misspellings in your application domain, for example, telmetry --> telemetry. It is a pain in the neck, of course.

Comment: that is what I was thinking...
however, I do not see how apache lucene / elastic search / ... can help me  : can you point me to the documentation which shows how to suggest only a word instead of a whole document ?